# Is this a problem with ASI or just the return grammar?

Tags: javascript

[People often talk](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#semicolon) about JavaScript's nasty ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion), and often cite [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/MGvNh/)...

```
function a() {
    return [
        'a',
        'b',
        'c'
    ];
}

function b() {
    return
    [
        'a',
        'b',
        'c'
    ];
}

console.log(a(), b());
// ["a", "b", "c"] undefined
```

Is there really a semicolon being inserted after `return` in `b()`, or does the JavaScript grammar state that the return value must explicitly be stated after it (i.e. no `\n`)?

Comment: You can find your answer on following link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a semicolon "inserted".  It's just that there's a parse ambiguity there, and the resolution is to treat the "return" and the following expression as two separate statements. I understand why it makes sense from a purely grammatical standpoint, but it seems like a weird decision in the *specific* case of the "return" statement as the decision is *guaranteed* to leave a never-executed orphan expression statement dangling after it.

I wonder how many aggregate SO rep points that trick has generated?

*edit 04 Apr 2014* — technically that decision to split the statement into two statements *is* called "semicolon insertion". Nobody actually sees the inserted semicolon; it's a figment of the parser's imagination :) The effect is the same whatever you call it.

Comment: Your answer makes sense of something that doesn't. Bravo :) +1

Comment: Take a look here: http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons concise and clear.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the spec that says a return value has to be on the same line as a return statement, it's just bad semi-colon insertion.

Comment: Doesn't this quote say otherwise? *return [no LineTerminator here] Expression;* from the [ECMASpec](http://es5.github.io/x5.html).