# What does ASI mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion)

I read an article discussing the semicolons in Javascript, and its author spoke about the ASI.

I don’t know what he’s talking about. Can anyone can explain it to me?

Thanks.

Comment: ASI stands for Automatic Semicolon Insertion.

Comment: Did the article use the term ASI without first defining it? Do you have a link?

Comment: Automatic Semicolon Insertion

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion

Comment: I suspect it’s [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232169/is-this-a-problem-with-asi-or-just-the-return-grammar).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Automatic Semicolon Insertion.

http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps they're talking about Automatic Semicolon Insertion

Here's a question that mentions it:  [Is this a problem with ASI or just the return grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232169/is-this-a-problem-with-asi-or-just-the-return-grammar)

Comment: Raw deal - comment 1.5 minutes late, lose out on 30 upvotes.