# jquery call function on click

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem calling a function on click. The following is my code:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    function showMessage(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    };      
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="ahaha"  onclick="$(this).showMessage('msg');" />
```

for some reasons I cant use `click()` function. Please  help me.

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

- `showMessage()` isn't a property of the jQuery object. It's just a regular function.
- If you're using jQuery, don't use `onclick`. Bind all events with JavaScript.

There are a few ways of fixing this code. Here's one:

**JavaScript**:

```
$.fn.showMessage = function(message) {
  alert(message);
};

$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).showMessage('I am a message');
  });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="button" value="ahaha" id="button" />
```

Comment: From all possible solutions, extending the jQuery object just makes the function more complex to call and adds the overhead of creating an unnecessary jQuery object..

Comment: What if `showMessage()` modifies the current object (hence the `$(this)`) to show the message?

Comment: I'll +1 as you're binding the listener, OP may decide what's important to keep or not besides that.

Comment: I liked the first point. To the point. Also the solution is quite cleaner and oo way :) +1

Answer (score 1):

without `$(this)` please.. Just call like this: `onclick="showmessage('msg')"`

Comment: I am on the phone man, i canot find the symbol for emphasizing the code :D

Comment: There, fixed the code. But I think there's still a closure problem with the function definition..

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
        function showMessage(msg) {
       alert(msg);
    };      <-----  i think this semicolon is not needed
        })  <-----  Should provide semicolon here as its the main function ending
```

Comment: That extra semi-colon doesn't make difference. [ASI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651231/what-does-asi-mean) takes care of the lacking semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways of doing this.

Let me make a few changes to your html,

```
<input id="myTest" value="CLICK ME!!!" title="HELLO WORLD!!!" type="button" />
```

next lets look at how to do this with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#myTest').click(function() {
    var el = $(this),
        msg = el.attr('title');
    alert(msg);
  });
});
```

Hope this helps,
Cheers